# Can a existing MVC2 application migrated to Azure Cloud Service Project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-2, azure-web-app-service

Currently I have MVC2 web application(on going). If I'm to use Azure PaaS (Platform as a Service), Can I use the existing project. Or should I create new project (using Cloud service project template)? Can it be migrated? And what kind of effort will it take for migration? Or should I rewrite the entire application with new project template?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to rewrite the project itself, you can simply add another project to your solution (which is a cloud project) and then point it to your other project in the associated definitions.

This is a useful technique when you already have existing projects that you want to migrate to Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would work with MVC 2 web application but you can simply try to convert the web application to Cloud Services project by right clicking on your project in Visual Studio (I used VS 2013), then `Convert` context menu and then selecting `Convert to Microsoft Azure Cloud Service Project`.

[image]